# Como parsear un String a enum en JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, parsear, enum

Mi pregunta es acerca de como puedo **parsear** un **String** y convertirlo en un **enum**. Os pongo en situación. Tengo un fichero csv tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este proyecto trata sobre los Premios Nobel, donde:

- **Year** es el año en el que se concedió.
- **Category** es la categoría.
- **Firstname** y **Surname** son los nombres y apellidos.
- **Gender** es el genero de la persona que lo ganó.
- **Birthyear** es el año de nacimiento.

El caso es que tengo que leer los datos del fichero CSV, por lo que e primer lugar voy a parsear cada linea del CSV con el siguiente método:

```
public class FactoriaNobel {
public Premio parsearLineaCSV(String lineaCSV) {
    Premio res = null;
    String [] trozos = lineaCSV.split(",");

    Integer anyo = new Integer (trozos[0].trim());
    String categoria = trozos[1].trim();
    String nombre = trozos[2].trim();
    String apellido = trozos[3].trim();
    Genero genero = new Genero (trozos[4].trim());
    Integer anyoNacimiento =  new Integer (trozos[5].trim());

    res = new PremioImpl(anyo, categoria, nombre, apellido, genero, anyoNacimiento);
    return res;
}
```

La clase Genero, es un **enum** tal que así:

```
public enum Genero {MALE, FEMALE}
```

Sin embargo me da fallo a la hora de parsear el enum:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Cannot Intantiate the type Genero

**¿Alguien sabría como puedo solucionarlo?
Muchas gracias.**

P.D.: El constructor de **Premios** tiene el siguiente formato:

> **PremioImpl (Integer, String, String, String, Genero, Integer)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> como puedo parsear un String y convertirlo en un enum??

Una manera sencilla sería utilizando el **método predefinido** dentro de un **enum** como **valueOf()**.

Esta sería su forma: `public static enum-type valueOf(String str)`

El cual devuelve la constante de enumeración del tipo de enumeración especificado.

---

Pienso que la manera adecuada de obtener el género sería así..

```
Genero genero = Genero.valueOf("cadena".toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un enum no se puede crear nuevas instancias, son estaticas. Puedes solucionarlo con un método estático en el enum tal que así:

```
public enum Genero {
    MALE, FEMALE

    public static Genero parse(String text){
        if(MALE.name().equalsIgnoreCase(text){
            return MALE;
        } else {
            return FEMALE;
        }
    }
}
```